# Skipping every even numbered item in the enumerate environment

Tags: lists, enumerate

How can I skip every even item in the `enumerate` environment without having to continually type `\setcounter{enumi}{5}`? I am still learning to program macros, so I spologize if this is a ridiculously easy question.

Just to be clear, I would like something like

`1. *Something.*
3. *Somthing else.*
5. *A third something.*`

...As opposed to

`1. Something. 
2. A second something. 
3. A tertiary Something.`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is for first level enumerations; other levels can be added in a similar way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{oddenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[oddenumerate]{start=0,label=\theoddenumeratei.}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\theoddenumeratei{\@arabic{\numexpr2*\value{oddenumeratei}+1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{oddenumerate}
    \item one
    \item two\label{two}
    \item three
\end{oddenumerate}

Here's a ref: \ref{two}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the scalability of this solution to include other numbering schemes.

Answer (score 5):

The following example defines macros `\arabicodd` and `\arabiceven` that works similar to `\arabic`, but using odd and even numbers respectively.

As in the other answers of cmhughes and egreg, the list is made via package `enumitem`.

References work in the same way as for the "normal" `enumerate` environment, especially, the dot is not included in the reference. The appearance of the label and reference can easily be configured options `label` and/or `ref`. The counters macros `\arabicodd` and `\arabiceven` can be used as `\arabic` there, because they are registered using `\AddEnumerateCounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\arabicodd}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@arabicodd\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\arabiceven}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@arabiceven\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@arabicodd}[1]{%
  \@arabic{\numexpr(#1)*2-1\relax}%
}
\newcommand*{\@arabiceven}[1]{%
  \@arabic{\numexpr(#1)*2\relax}%
}

\AddEnumerateCounter\arabicodd\@arabicodd{0}
\AddEnumerateCounter\arabiceven\@arabiceven{0}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
      \item one
      \item\label{normal:two}two
      \item three
  \end{enumerate}
  Middle label of normal numbered list: \ref{normal:two}.

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabicodd*.,ref=\arabicodd*]
      \item one
      \item\label{odd:two}two
      \item three
  \end{enumerate}
  Middle label of odd-numbered list: \ref{odd:two}.

  \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabiceven*.,ref=\arabiceven*]
      \item one
      \item\label{even:two}two
      \item three
  \end{enumerate}
  Middle label of even-numbered list: \ref{even:two}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is a really useful answer- while I wish I could mark both as the answer, the above answer gives finer control with fewer lines of code. Thanks again!