# How to change enumerate steps from 1 to 10

Tags: lists, enumerate, counters

I have an enumerate environment

```
\begin{enumerate}[font={\bfseries}, label={\arabic*}, wide=0pt, labelindent=1em, leftmargin=*]
    \item
\end{enumerate}
```

where \arabic counts in steps of 1 (1, 2, 3, 4 etc)
I know, I could just put a 0 behind \arabic*, but I would like to know if there is any functionality to change the counter steps of enumerate

Comment: You're going to have to perform a calculation anyway, so whether you "hack it" by adding a 0, or perform the calculation, it's probably the same.

Comment: What should it start with, 10?

Comment: how can I perform the calculation in this envoronment? I got lots of errors using \multiply and couldn't find out how to use it correctly

Comment: yeah start with 10 and increment by 10 for every item

Comment: See [Skipping every even numbered item in the `enumerate` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184198/5764).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47335/custom-enumeration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to define counter representations for any arithmetic progression.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \progression_evaluate:nnn
 {% #1 = start, #2 = difference, #3 = counter name
  \int_eval:n { #1 + ( #3 - 1 ) * #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \progression_evaluate:nnn { nnc }

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineprogression}{mmm}
 {% #1 = macro name, #2 = start, #3 = difference
  \cs_new:cn { __progression_\cs_to_str:N #1:n }
   {
    \progression_evaluate:nnc { #2 } { #3 } { c@##1 }
   }
  \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{#1}{m}
   {
    \use:c { __progression_\cs_to_str:N #1:n } { ##1 }
   }
  \exp_args:NNc \AddEnumerateCounter #1 { __progression_\cs_to_str:N #1:n } { 0 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineprogression{\bytens}{10}{10}
\defineprogression{\foo}{1}{5}

\newlist{tens}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tens,1]{
  label=\bytens*.,ref=\bytens*,
  font=\bfseries,
  wide=0pt,
  labelindent=1em,
  leftmargin=*
}

\begin{document}

This is numbered by tens
\begin{tens}
\item A
\item B
\item\label{C} C
\end{tens}

This is numbered like foo
\begin{enumerate}[label=\foo*.,ref=\foo*]
\item AA
\item BB
\item\label{CC} CC
\end{enumerate}

References: \ref{C} and \ref{CC}

\end{document}
```

[image]