# Step-by-step enumerate

Tags: enumerate, texmaker, enumitem

How I can to create a list with enumerate 2 by 2?
e.g.

```
1. ...
3. ...
5. ...
...
```

In general, How I can create a step-by-step list? Is it possible?

Comment: [Skipping every even numbered item in the enumerate environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184208/134144) might be helpful

Comment: @leandriis Thanks!